# parent child relationship query mistake in MongoDB in Action book

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, php-mongodb

[image]

I am suspecting the method defined to get siblings in the book [MongoDB in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182870)

Every category keeps parent_id that is the parent category id. So sibling categories should have common parent_id.

But to query siblings for a particular category (let's say `category['_id'] = C5`) book says following:

```
siblings = db.categories.find({'parent_id': category['_id']});
```

Returned cursor is obviously not siblings of C5, they are child of C5.

As per my understanding query should be

```
siblings = db.categories.find({'parent_id': category['parent_id']});
```

Please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, and this is fixed in the second printing of the book. See the errata here:

http://manning.com/banker/excerpt_errata.html